# CNAME to a secure url

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I have an AWS Elastic Load Balancer with the following secure url:

https://example.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

I also have the following 1&1 registered domain name:

`example.com`

I then in 1&1 config add a subdomain of `www` resulting in `www.example.com`.

I would like to add a `CNAME` alias to route traffic from the domain name to the ELB.

```
www.example.com -> https://example.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/
```

So I try add the `CNAME`:

[image]

As you can see, it is not accepting the url, as it is an `Invalid host name`.

I need the alias to pint to the secure (`https`) url. However, I think this may be the reason for the error.

**Question**

How do I set up a `CNAME` to point to a secure url?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

My Elastic Load Balanacer does have a secure listener.

[image]

Comment: _“How do I set up a CNAME to point to a secure url?”_ – you can’t, because CNAME does not “point to URLs” in the first place, it only points to host names. HTTP/HTTPS has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with this.

Comment: @CBroe, excuse my ignorance. How would I get traffic on my domain name to route to the secure url? (I want to go for the simplest and cheapest solution, so want to avoid Rout53 if possible). Is this possible via a `CNAME`? If so, what should the `alias` be?

Comment: CNAME only works on the DNS level, the resolving of a host name to an IP address. Users still access _your_ domain in their browser - so if you want to force HTTPS for that, then you should perhaps do this the usual way, check whether they used HTTP or HTTPS to access your site, and if it is HTTP only, redirect them to the corresponding HTTPS version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify `HTTPS` in your [NGINX](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx) using a `redirect` or [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) using `mod_rewrite`. If you want a little higher level HTTP to HTTPS roll over, you can do this (*most of the time*) in your application by specifying where your certs are located and doing a `listen` on Port 80 with a redirect/relocate to Port 443

On the DNS level you only specify the `location`. In your application, or on your server somewhere, you specify the `HTTP/HTTPS protocol`. [DNS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), being a protocol itself, cannot specify other protocols in its response. HTTPS is a processor intensive encryption operation done on your server.

I would highly recommend using [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) to assign a certificate to your domain. If you'd rather have it in your beanstalk application, check out [`letsencrypt`](https://letsencrypt.org/). It's a wonderful CLI tool for this stuff.

[Here is a helpful resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html)

## `Ubuntu + NGINX + letsencrypt`

Configuring HTTP to HTTPS on Ubuntu. Yes, only one operating system specific example, but `letsencrypt` should work anywhere with anything, anytime.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install letsencrypt
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo systemctl stop nginx    #if it starts by default...
sudo letsencrypt certonly --standalone -n -m richard@thewhozoo.com.com -d thewhozoo.com -d cname.thewhozoo.com --agree-tos
sudo ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/thewhozoo.com/    #you should see your stuff in this folder
sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem 2048    #make yo'self a diffie
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

**In your `default` file:**
(Snippets from: [HERE](https://www.bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx) and [HERE](https://www.bjornjohansen.no/optimizing-https-nginx) and [HERE](https://www.bjornjohansen.no/securing-nginx-ssl) and [HERE](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04))

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name thewhozoo.com www.thewhozoo.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name thewhozoo.com www.thewhozoo.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thewhozoo.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thewhozoo.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
}
```

Now that your NGINX file has your certs/keys/pems/whatever listed, you have to double check your firewall.
For Ubuntu and `ufw`, you can allow access via:

```
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
sudo ufw delete allow 'Nginx HTTP'
sudo ufw allow 'OpenSSH'
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
```

And you should see `Nginx HTTPS` enabled.
No matter what your flavor of HTTPS is (SSL, TLSvXX, etc.) you'll need Port 22 open on the firewall level cause they all use it, hense the `'OpenSSH'`.
**BE SURE TO RUN `allow 'OpenSSH'` BEFORE `ufw enable`. If you do not... your SSH session will be terminated and...good luck.**

Now your firewall is good to go, restart `nginx` and you *should* be set:

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

Helpful tips for the future:
NGINX by default set the renewal policy to 3 months. I'm not certain if this is a "standard" of internet law or not, but the add-on for renewing your certs is:

Add this to your `crontab`:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo letsencrypt renew
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

**HELPFUL NOTES:**

- You **must** have the domain name linked to the server of choice ***BEFORE*** running `letsencrypt`. It does a reverse IP Lookup to make sure you are the owner/admin of the domain.
- You do not *need* the giant list of encryption types but I would highly recommend keeping *most* of them. Elliptical Curve Diffie Hellman is a must for the type of key used above, but you can probably cut it down to `ECDH?E`, `AES`, `GCM`, and `RSA` or `SHA` depending on how many cipher suites you want to support. IF you *aren't* going to support `SSLvX` and only do `TLSvX` you only need to support (and restrict) the following: `ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DHE+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;`

## `AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) + Elastic Load Balancer`

- Go to your Load Balancer in the EC2 Resource Console
- Select your listener

  - Should probably say: `HTTPS: 443` in bold letters
- Check it and click Actions => Edit
- Double check that your Protocol is HTTPS on Port 443 and your target group is good
- At the bottom of the pop-up, select "Choose an **existing** certificate from AWS Certificate Manager (ACM)
- Then select your ACM Certificate
- Save it
- SSH into your instance/application on EBS/whatever
- Write an NGINX policy for redirecting HTTP traffic to HTTPS:

  ```
  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name thewhozoo.com www.thewhozoo.com;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  ```
- Restart NGINX

**For Elastic Beanstalk environment** check [THIS INFO](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/09/14/replacing-apache-with-nginx-on-elastic-beanstalk/).

Wait about 5 minutes for everything to sink in and you should be good to go!
[Check this for help if needed](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-certificate-manager-deploy-ssltls-based-apps-on-aws/)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense because I have now changed the CNAME and got www.thewhozoo.com to route to the server (load balancer), I see in Developer Tools, it's http and not https. I will try see if I can add a nginx redirect. Don't understand it yet, but will do some reading up.

Comment: Just a second then, I'll update my post with an NGINX HTTP to HTTPS roll over script

Comment: Thank you! appreciate the support

Comment: No problem, are you on Linux or Windows? Doesn't matter for NGINX but I'm putting in the full CLI walk through as well

Comment: I use a Macbook locally, and deploy to a Linux Tomcat Server on AWS (64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.6.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to update it with my ubuntu version not sure if Tomcat is `yum` or `apt-get` - it has been a while since I rolled anything out on EBS with Tomcat

Comment: Thank you. I have an `.ebextensions` directory with the server config files. So I guess it's adding more config there?

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer above. I have already used the `AWS Certificate Manager` to create a certificate and have the ELB running on `https`. So am I correct to assume, I don't need `letsencrypt`, and can proceed straight to "`In your default file`"? Also, my My ELB does have a secure listener already, see UPDATE in the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the update with ACM Certificates. I seem to already have this all configured (see UPDATE in my original question). Does that mean I only need to update the NGINX file to have the server redirect? Or is the ELB's Listener supposed to do that?

Comment: If you are only using ELB and ACM, it should be fully managed by AWS. ACM and the ELB Listener take care of renewal, protocol rollover, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it easier to implement. Do you think my ELB Listeners are set up incorrectly then? As the incoming domain (www.thewhozoo.com -> thewhozoo.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com) is not being redirected to https.

Comment: That screen shot _looks_ like it's from the Beanstalk console. Swap over to the EC2 Console and check out the same load balancer in there.

Comment: I have just updated the image to show more. I am sure it's from EC2. (apologies for my ignorance, I appreciate your support)

Comment: Interesting, it appears the `us-west-2` dashboard is different than the `us-east-1`. It also looks like your certificate is already set. Wait a little bit and see if it works. Otherwise, try turning off and removing all NGINX stuff because the listeners should take care of all this - make sure there's not a conflicting configuration

Comment: The thing is I don't have any NGINX stuff and I have had the ELB with its Listeners set up like this for a few days now. Do you think I should remove the top Listener (HTTP)? (The only change I have made today, is add the CNAME on 1&1 to point to the ELB). To me, it appears as if the Listeners accept traffic on those ports, but don't redirect any http traffic to https.

Comment: Ok, based on this article: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/ you **DO** have to do a NGINX redirect on your server side

Comment: Excuse the basic question, do I need to add the rewrite rule to a config file in `.ebextensions` directory of my war?

Comment: This article should help https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/09/14/replacing-apache-with-nginx-on-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: iSkore, please can you have a look at:  https://serverfault.com/questions/857962/apache-rewrite-rule-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Drop the 'http://' from the CNAME and just use:

```
example.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, will this resolve to the secure (https) site?

Comment: Yup - you're working at the DNS level here, not at the HTTP level.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record which details how CNAME's work and how they are used.

Comment: This kind of worked I think. But iI got to www.thewhozoo.com, I see in Developer Tools, it's http and not https.